# Why is springboot connecting to the default postgres database instead of my specified one?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, docker-compose

So I've got a springboot backend that I'm trying to connect to a postgres database. I've got a docker-compose file for it, yet the backend seems to connect to the wrong database. It seems to be connecting to the default postgres database instead of my specified vve database.

My docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  vve-postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=vve
      - POSTGRES_USER=vve
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - vve-postgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  vve-api:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST
      - DATABASE_PORT
      - DATABASE_NAME
      - DATABASE_USER
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD
    depends_on:
      - vve-postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  vve-postgres-volume:
```

My Environment file

```java
DATABASE_HOST=vve-postgres
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=vve
DATABASE_USER=vve
DATABASE_PASSWORD=admin
```

My application.properties

```java
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
server.error.include-message=always
```

Picture showing the two databases, I'm wrongly connected to the postgres@localhost

[image: Picture showing the two databases, I'm wrongly connected to the postgres@localhost]

How do I make sure my back end connects to the right database?

Comment: Have you tried to use plain application.properties next to the jar file? (I assume the one you have shown is a resource in jar)

Comment: How do I make sure my back end connects to the right database <-- change the DB password :)
As per my knowledge, we have to use different yml fields need to manage the environment and the environment selection should manage with your docker composer

Comment: You can hard code your application.properties first,  or even fill in wrong user name password to check whether it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Environment in docker compose should be key-value pair:

```
vve-api:
  build: .
  restart: on-failure
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    - DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
    - DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
    ...
```

Etc for each one